# IE doesn't display some images

Tags: html, internet-explorer

I have a few ".jpg" images on my website. They all are displayed correctly in every browser... except Internet Explorer. In IE, most of them are displayed, but there are also images that aren't displayed and there's a black-white cross instead of them. It's not a problem with wrong path because, as I said, other browsers are able to display the images.

Comment: Not enogh here for anyonr to do anything but guess. Some sample HTML pointing at the problem images would go a long way. You can edit yoir question and use the snippet button.

Comment: Are your ".jpg" images really jpgs and not renamed gifs, png or other image file format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check if your images are CMYK. They will only display if they are RGB.

Comment: Have a look here: https://tedgustaf.com/blog/2012/image-not-showing-in-ie8-due-to-cmyk-encoding/

Comment: Post the link with the images and I'll check for you

Comment: I checked them, they're RGB.

Comment: http://dl.dropbox.com/s/gdlz1unliodo5o1/baner.jpg?dl=1

Comment: It says that it is an invalid jpg file

Comment: Did you create the image? Windows viewer can open it, but Photoshop can't. You can always open it in Windows viewer and do a screenshot and save again as jpg rgb. Not a great solution I admit...

Comment: "Use Irfanview to open the image, if it is not actually a JPEG, Irfanview will tell you and ask if you want to change the extension to the correct one."

Comment: I opened it in Paint and resaved it as a jpg. Now it works for me in Internet Explorer

Comment: FYI it was actually a bmp file

Comment: OK, thank you for help, I'll make a screenshot - as you said. ;-)

Comment: Now, it works! :-)